How to horizontally align horizontal boxes in a vertical box?
In vertical mode, horizontal boxes are stacked one on top of the other and aligned to the left.  How can I get the boxes to align to the right instead?
\vbox{
  \hbox{short line}
  \hbox{looooooonger line}
}

\bye



The problem with tabular is that I'm using fonts of different sizes and I've found it produces inconsistent vertical spacing.

the default line spacing of boxes will be the same as that of tabular, so if that is the real issue you shoul dperhaps have given an example of that

you have tagged the question [tag:plain-tex] but your example is latex

@DavidCarlisle I will ask a different question later where it will become clear that tabular doesn't work in this situation. Also I changed the MWE so that it now is plain TeX.

tabular, in the end, just stacks boxes, and so it comes to the same thing as campa shows in the answer here. but yes feel free to ask a different question so an answer can make that more explicit.

The \ialign macro (a pre-initialized version of the \halign primitive) or the {tabular} environment:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The \TeX\ way:
\vbox{\ialign{\hfil#\cr
  short line\cr
  looooooonger line\cr}},
and the \LaTeX\ way:
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
  short line\\
  looooooonger line
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


